Suppose $M/G$ is a smooth quotient manifold and $N$ is a $G$-invariant submanifold of $M$. Then is $N/G$ a submanifold of $M/G$?
Let $M$ be a smooth manifold equipped with a, not necessarily proper, smooth Lie group action $G$. Suppose $M/G$ is a smooth quotient manifold. That is, there exists a smooth structure on the quotient space $M/G$ in which the quotient mapping $\pi:M \to M/G$ is a smooth submersion. Next, let $N$ be an embedded submanifold of $M$ that is invariant under $G$. That is, $x \in N$ implies $\pi(x) \subset N$. My question is, does there exist a smooth structure on the quotient space $N/G$ such that it is an embedded submanifold of $M/G$? I was able to show this in the case that $N$ is an open subset of $M$. However, what if $N$ is a closed embedded submanifold?

What you were able to show is simply false.

Can you provide a counter example?

Think about an $S^1$-action on $T^2$ and an invariant circle.

An invariant circle is not an open subset of $T^2$, if I am understanding correctly.

Of course $S^1$ cannot be an open subset in $T^2$.

@RobArthan: It is a counter-example to the claim about an open subset. This is what I said in the first comment. The counter-example is quite obvious, $T^2=S^1\times S^1$, take $S^1\times {p}$, it is a circle invariant under the obvious $S^1$-action. Its projection to $T^2/S^1$ is a point in $S^1$, hence, a smooth submanifold. OP claims that they can prove that in this situation the invariant subset is open. Clearly, it is not.

Since $N=S^1 \times {p}$ is not an open subset of $M=T^2$, then how is this a counterexample?

Oh, I misread your claim in the post.

@MoisheKohan Yes, I was able to show in the case that $N$ is an open subset of $M$. The proof follows from showing how the projection map restricted to $N$ is a smooth submersion, and how the subspace and quotient topologies of $N/G$ coincide.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
